# WPF Richtextbox - Clean Style and New Lines on TextChanged()

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

What is the best way to **clean** inserted **text style** (maybe on copy\paste) in `RichTextBox`?

and also I how to clean new lines from the user control to use it as **single line**? 
(when I set the `FlowDocument` , the new line remains).

I've searched for solutions over the net, but found nothing that works well with `WPF` `RichTextBox`.

Thanks.